# jPlayer 2.6.0 not playing audio throwing no supported source found error

Tags: wordpress, audio, jplayer

I am using jQuery jPlayer for audio files in [my project](http://109.74.4.178/csrsweden/agendapodden/). Earlier it was just fine but now all of a sudden it's just not working but throwing errors as:

1. GET http://traffic.libsyn.com/vemsagenda/vemsagenda0.mp3 net::ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE
2. Uncaught (in promise) DOMException: Failed to load because no supported source was found.
3. jPlayer 2.9.2 : id='jquery_jplayer_1' : Error!

It is not possible to play any media format provided in setMedia() on this browser using your current options.

Video or audio formats defined in the supplied option are missing.

Context: {supplied:'mp3'}

I am not getting idea as what is wrong all of a sudden. It was working just fine.

jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/bxwkyhsb/12/

Code:

```
$('#jquery_jplayer_1').jPlayer({
                    ready: function () {
                        $(this).jPlayer('setMedia', {
                            mp3: '".$audio_link[$i]."'
                        });
                    },
                    play: function() { // To avoid multiple jPlayers playing together.
                        $(this).jPlayer('pauseOthers');
                        equal_height_pod();
                    },
                    swfPath: 'js',
                    supplied: 'mp3',
                    wmode: 'window',
                    globalVolume: true,
                    smoothPlayBar: true,
                    keyEnabled: true,
                    preload: 'none',
                    errorAlerts: true,
                    warningAlerts: true
                });
                $('#jquery_jplayer_1').bind($.jPlayer.event.play, function() {
                        $('.jp-audio').removeClass('showcontainer').parent('figure').parent('.leftImg').parent('li').removeClass('titlewrap');
                $('#jp_container_1').addClass('showcontainer').parent('figure').next('.introtitle').addClass('wrapintrotitle');
                        $('#jp_container_1').parent('figure').parent('.leftImg ').parent('li').addClass('titlewrap'); 
                });
```

Any help/suggestions are welcome. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Post JSfiddle. Also you should upgrade to jPlayer 2.9.2. Are you sure the value of `'".$audio_link[$i]."'` is definitely a valid .mp3 url?

Comment: @ Martin Mazza Dawson ... yes the url is valid .mp3 ( http://traffic.libsyn.com/vemsagenda/vemsagenda0.mp3) and upgrading produced the same error as mentionsed above.

Comment: post a jsfiddle

Comment: @ Martin Mazza Dawson jsfiddle - https://jsfiddle.net/bxwkyhsb/12/

Comment: `supplied: 'mp3'`. Try that

Answer (score 0):

`supplied: 'mp3'`. Try that. It's missing in your example.

Comment: Then `'".$audio_link[$i]."'` must not be a valid url. Try debugging it and seeing the url because that JSFiddle works fine.

Comment: Does jsfiddle works in your browser ???  It doesn't work for me(chrome and firefox both)

Comment: Yeah mine is the same version Version 58.0.3029.110 (64-bit)

Comment: What error are you getting in the JSFiddle? The same as you posted in your question?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/144444/discussion-between-samjhana-joshi-and-martin-mazza-dawson).

Answer (score 0):

The code is working just fine. As @Martin Mazza Dawson said it's due to network problem(firewall). You can play it using chrome extension 'Browsec'.